# OpenGL, glDrawElementsInstanced behaving differently on NVIDIA GPU than AMD

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I have an AMD GPU on my desktop, AMD HD 5770. 
I am working on a project on my desktop for over a year. In the scene, I have instanced grass and instanced trees. Everything is working fine on desktop, as it should be.

I recently copied my code to my laptop, which has nVidia GPU. 
Here is the issue, the grass is rendering perfectly, but when it comes to trees, they're getting rendered on the same position, i.e. (0,0,0,0).
So, for example, if I want to render 10 trees at different locations, on AMD they get rendered at their respective positions, but on nVidia they all get rendered at the origin.

Here are the things that I made sure are correct- 

* first I checked if the positions are getting generated properly, the answer is YES they are. 
 * I checked if the layout location I am setting is correct.
 * I made sure that the parameters of glVertexAttribPointer are correct.
 
*  I made sure that I am sending data to the right layout variable.

* Installed 'fresh' nVidia drivers.

Here is the code for **instancing** and **shaders** respectively.

```
    //setting up the instanced buffer.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, iVBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); 
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); 
    glVertexAttribDivisor(0 ,1);
```

---

The vertex shader-

```
        mat4 m, m1;
        m = m4_model;

        vec4 pos = in_model_v4instancedPositions;
        //translate..
        m1[0] = vec4(i_scale, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        m1[1] = vec4(0.0, i_scale, 0.0, 0.0);
        m1[2] = vec4(0.0, 0.0, i_scale, 0.0);
        m1[3] = vec4(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, 1.0);
        m*=m1;

        mat4 mv = m4_view * m;

        //mat4 light_mvp = u_bias_proj_view_matrix *get_shadow_model();
        light_vertex_position = u_m4MVP_light * vec4(in_model_v3Position,1.0);
        vs_lightPosition=vec3(u_m4lightMatrix*vec4(uv3inLightPosition,1.0));

        vs_model_v2UV      = in_model_v2UV;
        vs_out.texcoord    = vs_model_v2UV;
        vs_model_v3Normal  = normalize(u_m3NormalMatrix * in_model_v3Normal);
        vs_model_v3Tangent = u_m3NormalMatrix * in_model_v3Tangent; 
        vs_model_v3Color   = in_model_v3Color;
        vs_model_v3Position= in_model_v3Position;

        gl_Position = m4_projection * mv * (vec4(in_model_v3Position,1.0));
```

I am out of ideas here, since the same code works perfectly fine on AMD.

Comment: In posted setup code `glVertexAttribPointer()` sets input for attribute with index `0`, but `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` enables attribute with index `5`. Probably irrelevant, since you geometry is being rendered correctly, but perhaps there are some mistakes in your code. Maybe your per-instance data is not set properly?

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek, The actual layout variable index was 5, I changed it for the simplicity, and as for the per-instance data, it is write, I debuged in application and made sure its correct, also trees are rendered properly on AMD GPU.

Comment: @2am that does not mean the code is OK. AMD drivers are usually more buggy (leftover from ATI) then the nVidia for OpenGL rendering (but they are much better then in the past). especially older drivers causes me a lot of headaches with need of excluding advanced rendering for some cards specifically (like HD5450) on some corporate Apps I had written in the past (VBO vas unusable reliably on those). You should also check the shader compilation log on booth gfx to see if something pops up. For those who not know how see GLSL compilation log in C++ –  Spektre 2 mins ago   edit

Comment: @Spektre, Wow, that is a news to me. I did observe some shadow issues on my nVidia build thought it must be because of a low end GPU of laptop. 

My primary development machine has AMD HD5770. I think for developing better quality product its best to shift to nVidia. 

I do check compilation log on client side, its clean.

Comment: @2am my observation on AMD/ATI drivers on top of their known OpenGL issues is also that if your App has any kind of memory leak (even unrelated to graphics) then sometimes weird stuff happens (like black color artifacts, driver crashes, geometry artifacts, etc). but as I said after AMD took over ATI the OpenGL drivers improved a lot so now they are at least usable (ATI was unable to write decend OpenGL driver for decades) at the cost of the franeworks need which is insain So I prefer nVidia all the time. If you use DX then AMD/ATI is better because nVidia has stability problems on DX for ages